# How do I enable Smart Zoom in OSX Lion only for Safari?

Tags: safari, osx-lion, touchpad

In OSX Lion, there are two trackpad system preferences I like: tap with two fingers to right click, and double tap with two fingers to zoom into content ("Smart Zoom"). The problem is that when both are enabled, there is a delay before the right click is registered, presumably while waiting so see if there will be a second tap.

I only really want the smart zoom behaviour in Safari, and the slow right click is annoying in games which use the right click. So, does anyone know how to turn smart zoom on on a program by program basis? I'd be happy to wrap the programs I want fast right clicks in with a script, so does anyone know how I can change the smart zoom setting from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: it appears that even with smart zoom turned off, if you double tap with your fingers far enough apart to not count as a right click, that the smart zoom triggers. It is a bit unreliable, but does work. Close enough for now I guess.